# In or On my gallery (phone)

Tags: prepositions

I want to assure myself if it's correct to say "I have his photo in my gallery", based on this [discussion](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/49189/in-on-the-app-store). Someone mentioned if I have stuff *in* app not on app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I (American English speaker) would say *in my gallery*, because I think of a gallery as a collection of photos.